# Expressjs add class to li element in partial

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this menu in a partial:

```
<ul id="submenu">
    <li><a href="/mypage/profile/<%=user[0].id  %>">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mypage/test/<%=user[0].id  %>">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

And these routes:

```
app.get('/mypage/profile/:id', function(req,res,next) {
    res.render('site/mypage/cv', {
        title: 'profile'
    });
});

app.get('/mypage/test/:id', function(req,res,next) {
    res.render('site/mypage/cv', {
        title: 'test'
    });
});
```

How can I add a class of `selected` to the li element depending on which link is clicked?

Comment: You mean how do you add a class to the page your are currently on right?

Comment: Yes exactly, so if im on the profile page, i want add e.g class="selected".Like `<li class="selected"><a href="/mypage/profile/<%=user[0].id  %>">Profile</a></li>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example, you don't need any server side stuff, you can achieve the effect with simple jQuery code (remember to include jQuery in the page before):

```
$(function() {
  // put the possible page titles here
  // they must be in the url also
  var possible_pages = ['profile', 'test'], 
      path = window.location.pathname,
      pattern, page, i, len;

  for (i = 0, len = possible_pages.length; i <= len; i++) {
    page = possible_pages[i];
    pattern = new RegExp(page);
    if (pattern.test(path)) {
      $('.submenu .' + page).addClass('selected');
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: and path.test is not a function

Comment: Ok i fixed it, i was in a hurry sorry :) It should be `pattern.test(path)` of course. Thanks. works great!