# How to get current url in view in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to change class of some menu items based on the current url being viewed by user in expressjs app. I am using ejs templating system in expressjs How do i pass current url and mangage current view class in links?
Should I pass current url vale in each res.render?
or is some variable passed in view that can be used?

Comment: If you want to use jQuery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489617/expressjs-add-class-to-li-element-in-partial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can actually use

```
//pass user data
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.locals.variable = req.variable;
next();
});
```

and access the variable in view file.

Comment: app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.current_path= req.path;
  next();
})

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the actual class or an indicator for which class to use as a template variable in res.render instead of passing the url and doing the actual parsing within the template.

Comment: so i should pass current url each time to res.render?